# What is the pythonic way to simply use one value or a few values when a function returns multiple values?

Tags: python

I am using a python socket and one of the API of the socket is

```
 (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
```

My magic number way is

```
 connected_sock = serversocket.accept()[0]
```

However, I am interested only in client socket and not address.
I can do so that there is just the client socket value and not address. What is the appropriate way in Python to do so that I can avoid magic numbers in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `_` as a [throwaway variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/9997212):

```
clientsocket, _ = serversocket.accept()
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `_` became a bit more than just a convention. Static analysis tools will not complain about `_` being defined but not used, nor about it being defined multiple times.

Comment: Your choices are `_` to indicate "I don't care", or `_socket` to indicate "I don't care for now, but I may need this in the future, so I want to remember that it's a socket.  In both cases, static analysis tools will not complain.